# how to read particular key value in string.xml on android?

Tags: android, listview, localization

`string.xml` contains lot of keys with value. I want to get particular value based on key.

For example, `string.xml` contains key1, key2 up to key100. I displaying these keys into `ListView`. If user select the key50 means I want to displaying the corresponding value in `TextView`. How to achieve this?

Sample `string.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="key1">value 1</string>
    <string name="key2"> value 2 </string>
     ...
     ...
    <string name="key100"> value 100 </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you show your String.xml file??

Comment: What exactly is in your ListView? Text strings such as "key1", "key2" etc. etc.? In that case you can get the value of the string resource by name - first get the id by calling the "getIdentifier" method in the "android.content.res.Resources" class (defType=string, defPackage=your package name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save your key as a string array resource like this

```
<string-array name="my_keys">
    <item>Key 1</item>
    <item>Key 2</item>
    <item>Key 3</item>
    <item>Key 4</item>
    <item>Key 5</item>
    <item>Key 6</item>
</string-array>
```

Populate the `listView` with the following code.

```
String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_keys);
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myKeys));
```

Retrieve the clicked item and put the value into the `TextView`

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      myTextView = ((TextView) view).getText();
    }
  });
```

Comment: This should be get the selected value in the `ListView`. But I want to get value from `string.xml` based this selected value.

Comment: The string.xml contains the string-array and other resources you define there. Its up to you to retrieve those variable based on the clicked item. Anytime you wish to read the value of a resource, just use `getResources()`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `<string name="key">string value</string>` resources then the only way is to access them by `key`:

```
String value = context.getString(R.string.key);
```

Btw, if you need to store some arbitrary data into your `Views` (the ones inside your ListView), use `view.setTag(object)` and `view.getTag()`.

Comment: yeah. I know. But I need to get particular key value based on user selection.

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically you can store/retrieve arbitrary objects inside the View.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) to get your value for keys.

Comment: Why dont you simply use the context.getResources.getString() ?